# Events in teamsite on save of component

Tags: content-management-system, teamsite, autonomy, interwoven

I need to trigger some action whenever user saves or updates a component.
I think one of the way is using event handler, but i am not sure how to achieve this functionality. Can someone guide me how i can implement this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are several events 
you can use the below code after ruleset

```
<script language="javascript" location="webserver" src="/iw/js/content_ads_toh.js"/>
<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[  

    IWEventRegistry.addFormHandler("onSave", autoName);

    ]]></script>
```

You can write the autoname function javascript and call that file as shown above  and include the function autoname in the file content_ads_toh

Let me know if you need more info on it